# Compare list of files using cygwin

Tags: batch-file, cygwin

I'm using cygwin for comparison count of files in 2 directories.
I'm using this script:

```bash
a=$(ls //NSVA/Matrical/Vitesse/REPORTS | grep .csv | grep $1 | grep -v Pull | wc -l)
b=$(ls //10.9.214.200/Lims/LimsLZ/starlims1/done/Nitrostore_stored/$1 | grep -v Pull |wc -l)

echo "Count of Uploaded files in NS is $a" 
echo "Count of Uploaded files in LZ is $b"

if [ $a -eq $b ]; then
    echo "Count MATCH!";
else
    echo "Count does NOT MATCH!!!";
fi;
```

Now I have to compare files in `$a` and `$b`. They should be identical but it could be that `$a` has more or `$b` has more.

Could someone please advice how to do it?

I have an idea like re-direct it to e.g. `$c` and `$d` and than grep it and etc but I have an issue with syntax.
I'd appreciate if someone could give me example of finding the difference of content between  those two directories.

Comment: Use `diff` command. See more [diff(1) manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to sync files, there is probably a better way (ie, `rsync`)

Anyway, given 2 directories with (mostly) the same content, you can use the `diff` utility.  It will tell you which files only exist in one directory or the other, and it shows you a difference of the contents of the (plain text only) files that have matching (sub paths and) names.

```
ivan@darkstar ~ $ ls dir1 dir2
dir1:
a  b

dir2:
a  c
ivan@darkstar ~ $ diff dir1 dir2
diff dir1/a dir2/a
1c1
< aa00_processes_machine
---
> 00_processes_machine
Only in dir1: b
Only in dir2: c
ivan@darkstar ~ $
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought about it but you please continue ,y case with it?

Comment: I have an issue with syntactic   Thanks again. I mean add diff to my code

Comment: Well in other words I can’t compare directories in my case because $a and $b are not directories but variable with a list of files. Either directories should be created and those files put there or still compare those two variables $a and $b. For some reason syntax does not work right for my case hence I would appreciate if someone could simply edit/modify my example.

Answer (score 0):

Well ... never mind my question because I resolved it myself.
I was able to redirect the output of each variable in 2 files. Than I ran grep -vf   and it worked for me.
Thanks anyway..